# Audio file plays automatically when going back to the previous page

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, iframe

I have audio/videos that you can play in a portfolio area on my website.
If I play one of them, and then go the previous page, and then back to my page using next button of my browser, the audio will play automatically even though I didn't click on anything.
The exact same behaviour will occur if I play a video or audio, click to visit another page, and then click on the previous page button of my browser.

How could I prevent that?

Here's some code :

```
<iframe class="ms-slide-video" src="about:blank" allowfullscreen="true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none;"></iframe>
```

Gets transformed to :

```
<iframe class="ms-slide-video" src="/dacontent/video/mp4/2205.mp4?&amp;autoplay=1" allowfullscreen="true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; opacity: 1;"></iframe>
```

When I click on play.

But when the bug occurs, the iframe's src stays "about:blank".

Here's the iframe content at all time :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
<video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
<source src="http://www.kang.fr/dacontent/video/mp4/2205.mp4?&amp;autoplay=1" type="video/mp4"></video>
</body>
</html>
```

I found and tried removing "&autoplay=1" in the src attribute of source, with no success. Couldn't find out how to change video's autoplay attribute though.

Comment: `<audio autoplay="false"></audio>` maybe ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using Masterslider which generates iframe and put audio tags and video tags in them, so I don't know if I can do anything about written tags in the first place :/

Comment: I think you might need to show us some code. IE, what you have currently. Without that, there's little chance we can help you given your reply to the comment.

Comment: I edited my original post with a lot more code involved.

Comment: I'm looking into the Masterslider documentation.  Are you using the jQuery version, or the Wordpress version?

Comment: I'm using the jQuery version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have resolved my issue.

First, as I said :

> But when the bug occurs, the iframe's src stays "about:blank".

This was **wrong**. My browser inspector was blatantly lying to me about those iframes. Actually, the src attribute was filled with the video link.

So I had to empty the attribute of those iframes, but **only** when the page was fully loaded. Before that, it wouldn't be any use because the iframes were not generated yet.

Here's the final code (it is specific to Masterslider's slides, but will work for any iframe that causes this problem).

```
jQuery(window).load(function ($) {
    if (jQuery('iframe.ms-slide-video').length) {
        jQuery('iframe.ms-slide-video').attr('src', '');
    }
});
```